# jquery .addClass not doing what it's supposed to

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, vb.net

I'm trying to highlight a list element using:

`element.id = 'ACT_3'`

`$('#' + element.id).addClass('highlight');`

**Javascript**

```
function selectItemId(element) {
    $('#' + element.id).addClass('highlight');

    var eleID = element.id;
    //highlight selection(s)
    selectItemId

    if (document.getElementById(eleID).className == "smallfieldchecked") {
        document.getElementById(eleID).className = "smallfield";
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById(eleID).className = "smallfieldchecked";
    }

    Items.selectedForRemoval.length = 0;

    // build a list of Selected Items    
    if (elementInDocument(document.getElementById(mainGrid))) {
        var ul = document.getElementById(mainGrid);
        var lis = ul.childNodes;

        for (var x = 0; x < lis.length; x++) {
            if (document.getElementById(lis[x].id)) {
                if (document.getElementById(lis[x].id).className == "smallfieldchecked") {
                    Items.selectedForRemoval.push(lis[x].id.replace(rowPrefix, ''));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**CSS**

```
.highlight {
    background-color: cyan;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: `.className=` will replace the class, so replace whatever you did with `.addClass` - you might like to stick with jquery methods: `.addClass("class")` `.removeClass("class")` and `.is(".class")` (note `.` for `.is()`)

Comment: You do not need an `if` statement, use `.toggleClass("smallfieldchecked smallfield");` and the two classes will be swapped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a few variations of how to fix the issue. Sélim Achour is correct in the cause of the problem and how to fix it.

Every time you do a query, you have to search the DOM for it, so these examples will put the element into a reuseable var.

```
function selectItemIDFromMainGrid(element) {
    var $element = $('#' + element.id);
    $element.addClass('highlight');

    //highlight selection(s)
    selectItemIDFromMainGrid // <-- not sure what this is

    if ($element.hasClass("smallfieldchecked")) {
        $element.removeClass('smallfieldchecked').addClass("smallfield");
    }
    else {
        $element.removeClass('smallfield').addClass("smallfieldchecked");
    }

    // remaining code removed for brevity.
}
```

This version also works, as Sélim Achour pointed out. However, you will have to debug a similar situation if you have more classes used in the future.

```
function selectItemIDFromMainGrid(element) {
    // jquery-wrapped element
    var $element = $('#' + element.id);

    // actual DOM element.
    var domElement = $element[0];

    //highlight selection(s)
    selectItemIDFromMainGrid // <-- not sure what this is

    if ($element.hasClass("smallfieldchecked")) {
        domElement.className = "smallfield";
    }
    else {
        domElement.className = "smallfieldchecked";
    }

    // adding the class down here after setting the class above
    // makes this get appended. the assignments above make a single class assignment.
    $element.addClass('highlight');

    // remaining code removed for brevity.
}
```

Or you can skip the jQuery for adding the highlight class.

```
function selectItemIDFromMainGrid(element) {
    // jquery-wrapped element
    var $element = $('#' + element.id);

    // actual DOM element.
    var domElement = $element[0];

    //highlight selection(s)
    selectItemIDFromMainGrid // <-- not sure what this is

    if ($element.hasClass("smallfieldchecked")) {
        domElement.className = "smallfield highlight";
    }
    else {
        domElement.className = "smallfieldchecked highlight";
    }

    // remaining code removed for brevity.
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the in depth response, much appreciated. Unfortunately none of the solutions worked. I tried commenting out the rest of the code completely and leaving only the stuff relevant for highlighting and even that didn't work.

Comment: If the highlight word is disappearing from the class, maybe another code somewhere is overriding the class. You could add an attribute `data-highlight="true"` and then in css `li[data-highlight=true] { ... }`

Answer (score 1):

I think the `addClass()` is working but it's being overridden a few lines below by `document.getElementById(eleID).className = "...."`

Try to put the `addClass` line after the `if ... else` block

Comment: Thanks, looks like that was not the main issue. I tried commenting out the rest of the code completely and leaving only the stuff relevant for highlighting and even that didn't work